# Display Regular & Sale Price for variable products on shop page - WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, price, product-variations

I have a website with all the products having 2 variation attributes.

1. Normal Item
2. Exchange Item

Normal Item variation has a "Regular Price" & "Sale Price" compulsory. Exchange Item variation has only 1 regular price. I want to show all the 3 prices on the shop page where all the products are seen. I found the following code in `woocommerce/templates/loops/price.php`

```
<?php if ( $price_html = $product->get_price_html() ) : ?>
    <span class="price"><?php echo $price_html; ?></span>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The same code is fetching different results for different themes, I dont understand what is causing this. For some themes it shows range of prices. For my theme this is displaying only the lowest price out of the 2 variations. How can I show something like this:

1. Regular Price: 1000 (strikethrough)
2. Sale Price : 800
3. Exchange Price: 600

Number one and two being the regular & sale price of variation 1 of the product while number 3 is the regular price of variation 2.

Follwing is just and example of how I want it to be. striked is the regular price, 'with old battery' is the exchange price, and 'without old battery' is Regular price from normal item variation.
[image]

---

**EDIT:** So I checked function.php which has this code

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_sale_price_html', 'wc_wc20_variation_price_format', 10, 2 );
 add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'wc_wc20_variation_price_format', 10, 2 );
 function wc_wc20_variation_price_format( $price, $product ) {
 // Main Price
 $prices = array( $product->get_variation_price( 'min', true ), $product->get_variation_price( 'max', true ) );
 $price = $prices[0] !== $prices[1] ? sprintf( __( 'Price: %1$s', 'woocommerce' ), wc_price( $prices[0] ) ) : wc_price( $prices[0] );
 // Sale Price
 $prices = array( $product->get_variation_regular_price( 'min', true ), $product->get_variation_regular_price( 'max', true ) );
 sort( $prices );
 $saleprice = $prices[0] !== $prices[1] ? sprintf( __( 'Previous Price: %1$s', 'woocommerce' ), wc_price( $prices[0] ) ) : wc_price( $prices[0] );
 if ( $price !== $saleprice ) {
   $price = '<ins>' . $price . '</ins> <del>' . $saleprice . '</del>';
 }
   return $price;
 }
```

Gets me only exchange price values, I would like to get all.